# HashMap putAll not adding any elements

Tags: java, hashmap

**Problem**

If I explicitly loop through every element in hash map A and "put" each element in hash map B then I have no problem. But if try calling `A.putAll(B)` for some reason B ends up null.

The code that is working is the basic iterator approach show below:

```
    Iterator it = A.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        B.put((Integer)entry.getKey(),(Integer)entry.getKey());
    }
```

Where I run into trouble is when I do this.

```
HashMap A = loadHashMapWithData();
HashMap B = new HashMap();
A.putAll(B);
System.out.println(A);
System.out.println(B);
```

The second hashmap I am trying to pass data into always ends up "null".
Going forward I am using the 1st approach but it would be nice to know why putAll is failing.

Comment: B = empty map. Add B to A. "Help, B is empty". DO I get your question right?

Comment: I'm trying to copy data in A into B. B is empty.

Comment: B.putAll(A); it is then.

Comment: Nice. That was my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A.putAll(B)` is putting all of the elements from `B` into `A` - I think you want `B.putAll(A)` which puts all of the elements from `A` into `B`

`object.method(parameter)` calls `method` on `object` passing in `parameter` - you want to call `putAll` on `B`, so `B` is your `object`